# Rails convert computed array of hashes into a nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, hash, attributes

This query response contains a `delta` pair that is computed so that I don't have to unnecessarily create another column in the database.

```
records = [
  {"credential_id"=>1, "followers_count"=>10000, "created_at"=>"2017-02-26 18:50:20.654996", "delta"=>nil}, 
  {"credential_id"=>1, "followers_count"=>12000, "created_at"=>"2017-02-27 18:50:20.654996", "delta"=>2000}, 
  {"credential_id"=>1, "followers_count"=>15000, "created_at"=>"2017-02-28 18:50:20.654996", "delta"=>3000}
]
```

Desired result:

```
deltas = [
  [2017-02-26 18:50:20.654996, nil],
  [2017-02-27 18:50:20.654996, 2000],
  [2017-02-28 18:50:20.654996, 3000]
]
```

*Attempts* -- However, I think the fact that `:delta` is not part of the model/table is preventing me from using the following solutions: `.pluck(:created_at, :delta)`, `.values_at("created_at", "delta")`, and

```
attributes = [:created_at, :delta]    

records.map do |record|
  attributes.map { |attr| record[attr] }
end
```

I've run out of solutions to try. Can you help me find the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simple:

```
records.map { |h| [h['created_at'], h['delta']] }
 => [["2017-02-26 18:50:20.654996", nil], 
     ["2017-02-27 18:50:20.654996", 2000], 
     ["2017-02-28 18:50:20.654996", 3000]]
```

In Ruby, you can access hash value by passing key name in brackets, like in this instance.

Or you can use [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
records.map { |h| h.values_at('created_at', 'delta') }
```

and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the records hash with `.map`, and assign the 'created_at' and 'delta' fields to a new array. `Array#map` allows you to mutate the starting objects as you go.

```
records.map {|r| [r['created_at'], r['delta']]}
```

From the docs:

> Array#map
>
> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

[Ruby Docs for map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-map)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the attributes symbols with strings :

```
attributes = ['created_at', 'delta']
```